# Why is this Excel document showing as Unclassified?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have tried googling this but to no avail. My colleague has had this come up on her Excel,at first I thought it might be licence issue but her other MS software is fine.

Why is this unclassified and why is it stopping it from functioning correctly, i.e. formulas are not calculating? Any help is much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by unclassified ? and what is the image showing ?

Comment: There is an orange bar coming up at the foot of the spreadsheet which says 'unclassified' in it. I have never seen it before. Also, where the copy and paste buttons would normally be there is a 'classification' button.

Comment: what options are available when you click on that box ? have you checked it is not an add in ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some kind of web form for email encryption has been installed.

See website below:

https://www.egress.com/what-we-offer/secure-web-form

Try uninstalling it using the below steps.

1. Click Start, and then go to Control Panel.
2. Select Programs, and then click Programs and Features.
3. Find out Egress Switch option and then select it, click Uninstall.

If that fails you can contact the company directly through their support page:

https://www.egress.com/support

Comment: Thank you Peter, I think you have hit the nail on the head there, much appreciated.

Comment: no probs @BenNicholas